# Nested table for type inheritance

Tags: oracle, nested-table, object-relationships

I'm manipulating a type and use inheritance. My child have a collection in it and when I try to create a table from the mother and add the 'nested table name_collection_of' the child type in the creating table, I get an error that the identicator no valid. How can I resolve this?

```
-- Definir le type tcage
create type tcage as object (
    noCage number(3),
    fonction varchar2(20),
    noAllee number(3)
);
/

-- Definir une collection libre ens_cages de references sur tcage
create type ens_cages as table of ref tcage;
/

-- Definir une collection statique (Varray) tspecialites de chaines de caracteres (fonction de la cage)
Create type tspecialites as Varray(10) OF varchar(30) ;
/

-- Definir un type temploye
create type temploye as object(
    nomE varchar2(20),
    adresse varchar2(20),
    fonction_cage tspecialites
)
not final
;
/


-- Definir les sous-types de temploye: tgardien et trespsonsable
create type tgardien under temploye (
    liste_cages ens_cages);
/

create type tresponsable under temploye (
    noAllee number(3) );
/

-- Creation de la table lesemployes (avec nomE comme cl� primaire )
--  sans oublier la nested table
create table lesemployes of temploye ( PRIMARY KEY (nomE) );
nested table liste_cages store as cages;
```

I get this error when executes this code :

```
nested table tgardien.liste_cages store as cages
             *
ERREUR a la ligne 4 :
ORA-00904:  : identificateur non valide
```

So I've tried with this :

```
nested table tgardien.liste_cages store as cages
```

But it didn't work, still the same error. How can I deal with this,please?

Answer (score 0):

You use:

```sql
create table lesemployes of temploye ( PRIMARY KEY (nomE) );
```

Which works.

However:

```sql
create table lesemployes of temploye ( PRIMARY KEY (nomE) )
nested table liste_cages store as cages;
```

*Note: no `;` at the end of the first line.*

Will not work as `temploye` does not have an attribute `liste_cages` as that is an attribute of a sub-type and not of the super-type that you are using to define the table.

I do not think that it is possible to do what you want. To define a nested table, the attribute that is being nested would have to be on the super-type rather than a sub-type of that type.

Comment: I already deleted the comma in the first line but the problem was like you said, the liste_cages belongs to the sub-type so, it won't work in the super-type.